# Failed to execute goal -checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check (validate) on project client-examples

Tags: m2eclipse, opc-ua, milo

Failed to build the client examples.

> C:\Users\predix\Desktop\OPC\milo-master\milo-examples\client-examples\src\main\java\org\eclipse\milo\examples\client\ClientExampleRunner.java:2: Line does not match expected header line of ' * Copyright (c) \d\d\d\d.*$'. [RegexpHeader]

Answer (score 0):

The checkstyle plugin is failing because that file does't have the license header it expects. Did you modify it?

Comment: No i haven't modify anything yet just i have imported the client-examples

Comment: Hi kaven how to get the connection status of client whether it is connected to server or not? DO u have any docs for this code?